# How to make an Object emit Particles [JS]

Tags: javascript, particles, particles.js

I'm currently making an overlay and I want to make it emit particles out of the top which overtime or length get less and less visible.
Sadly the only information I found about JS particles is how to make backgrounds with particles in them. It works that I make such a background with alpha 0 as color and move it behind the overlay but that solution isn't really clean. Also regarding that, the shape is a skewed rectangle the part of the particle container under one of the rectangles corner is still visible which looks pretty bad. Is there a way to do it better?
Besides that, I couldn't find out how to make them continuously lose visibility till they are invisible after a distance or time amount but I think that's a relatively easy question.

I hope you can help me, stay safe, and have a great day ^^

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
canvas{ display: block; vertical-align: bottom; }

#particles-js {
position:absolute;
width: 560px;
height: 110px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
background-image: url("");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
top: 135px;
left: 200px;
}

.count-particles {
background: #000022;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 80px;
color: #13E8E9;
font-size: .8em;
text-align: left;
text-indent: 4px;
line-height: 14px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.js-count-particles {
font-size: 1.1em;
}
#stats, .count-particles {
-webkit-user-select: none;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
#stats {
border-radius:
3px 3px 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.count-particles{ border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px; }

#TopPart {
  position: relative;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #00ee97;
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 27.5px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
"polygon":{"nb_sides":5},
"image":{"src":"img/github.svg","width":100,"height":100}},
"opacity":{"value":0.5,"random":false,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":1,"opacity_min":0.1,"sync":false}},
"size":{"value":3,"random":true,"anim":{"enable":false,"speed":40,"size_min":0.1,"sync":false}},
"line_linked":{"enable":false,"distance":150,"color":"#ffffff","opacity":0.4,"width":5},
"move":{"enable":true,"speed":2,"direction":"top","random":false,"straight":false,"out_mode":"out",
"bounce":false,
"attract":{"enable":false,"rotateX":600,"rotateY":1200}}},
"interactivity":{"detect_on":"canvas","events":{"onhover":{"enable":false,"mode":"repulse"},
"onclick":{"enable":false,"mode":"push"},"resize":true},
"modes":{"grab":{"distance":400,"line_linked":{"opacity":1}},
"bubble":{"distance":400,"size":40,"duration":2,"opacity":8,"speed":3},
"repulse":{"distance":200,"duration":0.4},
"push":{"particles_nb":4},
"remove":{"particles_nb":2}}},"retina_detect":true});
var count_particles, stats, update; stats = new Stats; stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement); count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles');
update = function() { stats.begin();
stats.end();
if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array)
{ count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length; }
requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);;
```

https://codepen.io/spielefresser/pen/poeXWJq

Comment: Others could follow your code better, if it was formatted. Consider using [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) to format it for you.

Comment: @s-b Do you want an effect like this? https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/NWRPKQW This is made with tsParticles: https://particles.js.org (a fork of Particles.js, with new features like emitters and bugs fixed)

Comment: @Moritz Mahringer I'm sorry if I had written the code it would look better (CSS TopPart for example) but I used the codepen of Particles.js and they apparently do not format their code. I didn't know about prettier tho thanks ^^

Comment: @Caelan Not exactly like this but with a bit of customization I got the effect I want ^^

Comment: Ok, in theory at least. As soon as I implement it in my overlay I'm getting
"ReferenceError: tsParticles is not defined"
I tried copying the entire code of the fire effect in a new codepen and I'm getting the same error.
Is there something I'm missing? It should at least work for the fire effect.

Comment: Did you include the tsParticles script in your page? You can find it in the CodePen sample settings or you can read more about it on GitHub https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles

Comment: @Caelan nope I forgot about that xD Thank you ^^